# TYPO3 perform action only once when multiple same plugins on page

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I want editors to be able to insert a plugin multiple times on a page.

Under each record item on the frontpage, there are f:link.actions helpful / not helpful, which could show a comment form.

```
?tx_bla[question]=2&tx_bla[helpful]=0&tx_bla[action]=helpfulness&tx_bla[controller]=Question
```

When inserted the plugin twice on a page and clicking on the above link, the action will run twice and show 2 forms.

How can I set that actions only run for the current plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by getting in the list action the current uid of the plugin

```
$cObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
$currentUid = $cObj->data['uid'];
```

assign it to the view and send as argument to the action. There compare the 2 uid's.

Answer (score 1):

Every plugin listens to its GET parameter, that's why two same plugins do the same.

Either you change one plugin to not react on the GET parameter or you add a GET parameter to identify the plugin which should handle it.

Comment: OK thx, I was hoping there would be a core solution for this.